# Import and execute all files on folder with es6

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6

I am migrating some node ES5 node code to Typescript. I need to port these two pieces of code where I iterate through all the files in a directory and call the default function these files are exporting. How would I do that in Typescript or ES6?

models/index.js

```
const fs = require("fs");

module.exports = () =>
  fs.readdirSync(__dirname).map((model) => {
    if (model === "index.js") return;
    return require("./" + model);
  });
```

index.js

```
const modelDefiners = require("./models")();

for (const modelDefiner of modelDefiners) {
  if (typeof modelDefiner === "function") {
    modelDefiner();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with dynamic imports:

```
import { promises as fs } from 'fs';
import { join } from 'path';

export default async function*() {
  for (const model of await fs.readdir(__dirname)) {
    if (model === "index.js") continue;
    yield await import(join(__dirname, model));
  }
}
```

```
import modelDefiners from "./models";

(async () => {
  for await (const {default: modelDefiner} of modelDefiners()) {
    if (typeof modelDefiner === "function") {
      modelDefiner();
    }
  }
})();
```

Comment: Why use an async generator?

Comment: @loganfsmyth Because I can? :P Making a promise for an array would work as well.

Comment: Thanks @Bergi . Would you mind ellaborating a bit more on why an async generator? The code works perfectly after fixing a few typos, create gist here https://gist.github.com/oliverasistemas/c68c010bc61d049adeee3bb44b390f12 if you want to check the corrected code. If there a "simpler" or at least "alternative" approach I would love seeing it.

Comment: The async generator is a quite elegant solution for loading the modules sequentially. The alternative would be a standard `return Promise.all((await fs.readdir(__dirname)).filter(model => model !== 'index.js').map(model => import(join(__dirname, model)))));`

Answer (score 0):

__dirname is no longer valid with ES6.
See https://blog.logrocket.com/alternatives-dirname-node-js-es-modules/
for details